# Cannot cross-compile proto files for ARM but its working for x86_64

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm working on a C++ project where I need to cross-compile `.proto` files for ARM. I work with Yocto so I have a SDK with the rootfs and also a shell script which sets up the environment variables. When compiling for ARM from the x86_64 host I use the x86_64 `grpc_cpp_plugin` so the host machine can execute it.

The problem is that when trying to cross-compile the `.proto` files I get the following error:

```
[build] protoc-gen-grpc: program not found or is not executable
[build] Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
[build] --grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

My cmake is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(ProtoFiles)
file(GLOB_RECURSE proto-files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/" "*.proto")

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} MATCHES "x86_64")
    set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/x86_64/gRPC/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin")
else()
    set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain/sysroots/x86_64/usr/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin")
endif()

add_library(ProtoFiles OBJECT ${proto-files})

target_link_libraries(ProtoFiles PUBLIC protobuf::libprotobuf gRPC::grpc gRPC::grpc++)

set(PROTO_BIN_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build_proto")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PROTO_BIN_DIR})
set(PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/proto")

target_include_directories(ProtoFiles PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROTO_BIN_DIR}>")

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET ProtoFiles
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR ${PROTO_BIN_DIR})

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET ProtoFiles
    LANGUAGE grpc
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_BIN_DIR}")
```

When building the project I get the `.pb.cc` and `.pb.h` files, so protoc seems to work correctly(?), but the `.grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc` are missing. Building for x86_64 works. When I try to execute the plugin manually it also seems to work (I don't get an output, but according to my research thats ok). Executing `protoc` with the `grpc_cpp_plugin` using the console also works. The paths seem also to be correct.
Can someone help me?
`protoc --version` reports 3.15.2

Edit:
@Tsyvarev suggested adding a `execute_process` to the `CMakeLists.txt` so I replaced

```
protobuf_generate(
    TARGET DGA.Proto
    LANGUAGE grpc
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_BIN_DIR}")
```

with

```
set(PROTOC_COMMAND ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain/sysroots/x86_64/usr/bin/protoc)
set(PROTOC_CMD_PATH --proto_path=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
set(PROTOC_GRPC_OUT --grpc_out=${PROTO_BIN_DIR})
set(PROTOC_PLUGIN --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE})

execute_process(
    COMMAND ${PROTOC_COMMAND} ${PROTOC_CMD_PATH} ${PROTOC_GRPC_OUT} ${PROTOC_PLUGIN} ${proto-files}
)
```

With this change I get the `.grpc.pbcc` and `.grpc.pb.h` files.

Comment: "When I try to execute the plugin manually it also seems to work" - Do you mean that you attempted to use plugin from `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain/sysroots/x86_64/usr/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin`? You may try to add to your `CMakeLists.txt` a call to `execute_process` which executes protobuf with the given plugin. That way you may verify that your plugin actually works in the environment, where `protobuf_generate` is executed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the suggestion! I edited my question to add the suggested `execute_process`, it seems to work (at least I get the `.grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc` files, didn't try to build the project yet). Do you maybe have an idea why the protobuf_generate with the plugin doesn't work?

Comment: You don't show how you include Protobuf support to your code. Are you sure that you include it in a way which uses `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain/sysroots/x86_64/usr/bin/protoc` as variable `Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE`? (You may print value of that variable in your `CMakeLists.txt`)

Comment: @Tsyvarev I printed the variable `Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE` and both execute_process protec and the executable point to `/home/31ank/Documents/Git/ARMCom/toolchain/sysroots/x86_64/usr/bin/protoc`